# Extracting hrefs within bunch of unique div class using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner and I am trying to scrape `a hrefs` which are embedded in a bunch of `div class`, respectively. When I inspect elements it looks like this:

```
<div class="item hentry" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" data-id="1252224732659290211">
<img class="thumbnail" src="//img.youtube.com/vi/fX_kx_drRsY/0.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
  <h3 class="title entry-title" itemprop="name">
    <a href="the link i want to extract"</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I have been searching at Stackoverflow but most of the examples were where `div class` was fixed, my page has div classes that are not fixed, the data ids are different.

I tried using the following but I think it only works when div class is fixed?

```
with open("list_of_urls.txt", "wb") as f:
    for item in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "item hentry"}):
        for link in item.find_all('a'):
            f.write("%s\n" % link["href"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
soup.select('div[class] a')  # find all a tags under the div tag which has class attribute
```

Use [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)